# Incorrect MySQL query update

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to filtering database records if there is duplicate records I will mark the records as `deleted = 1`. Unfortunately I'm not able to update my records correctly, I did try use `limit 1` for updating the records but I only update 1 record only and if I didn't use the `limit 1` it will update entire records.

[image]

The above is my database table, what I need to do is, assume there is bunch of records with different `point_id` and I filtered to `1` only. Now I would like to query the records sort by date `ASC` and update all the records to `deleted = 1` expect the last record.

Here is my source code. The problem I facing now is it will update all the records, and if I using `LIMIT 1` it only will update 1 record only.

```
while($total > 1){
    $total--;
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT * 
        FROM customers_profiles_game_logs 
        WHERE point_id='$points_filter_row[point_id]' 
        AND customer_id='$sql_customer_row[customer_id]'
        ORDER BY date_created ASC");
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    for ($i = 1; $i < $num_rows; $num_rows--) {
       echo $sqli = sprintf("UPDATE customers_profiles_game_logs 
           SET deleted='1' 
           WHERE customer_id='$sql_customer_row[customer_id]'
           AND point_id='$row[point_id]' LIMIT 1"); 
             mysql_query($sqli) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Comment: do you wants to update all rows or one row

Comment: @jmail I want to update all rows except last record.

Comment: check my answer. with sql fiddle here

Answer (score 2):

You can have a subquery which gets the record to be updated and join it with the table itself, eg.

```
UPDATE  customers_profiles_game_logs a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  customer_id, MIN(date) date
            FROM    customers_profiles_game_logs
            WHERE   customer_id = 1                -- <== ID HERE
        ) b ON  a.customer_id = b.customer_id
                AND a.date = b.date
SET     a.deleted = 1
```

if you remove the `WHERE` clause inside the subquery, all the first record for each customer will be updated.

Comment: It only update 1 row only, what I need is it will update all the rows expect the last record.

Answer (score 0):

***you need this:***

```
  UPDATE  customers_profiles_game_logs a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  customer_id, MIN(date) date
            FROM    customers_profiles_game_logs
            WHERE   customer_id = 1                -- <== ID HERE
        ) b ON  a.customer_id = b.customer_id
            SET     a.deleted = 1
```

## http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c440/1

***another style:***

```
UPDATE  customers_profiles_game_logs a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  customer_id, MIN(date) date
            FROM    customers_profiles_game_logs
        ) b ON  a.customer_id = b.customer_id
            SET     a.deleted = 1
```

## http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88e7c/1

Comment: @Jien Wai, did you check my answer or not.

Comment: yes but this is not what I need. Here is my SQL `http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02866/1` what I need is I want to update `point_id = 2` and don't update the latest day means the `log_id 19` I won't update.